# SharePoint 2010 workflow not starting

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have an issue with a SharePoint 2010 list workflow created in SharePoint Designer that is not starting. I have one list where list items are edited and then a workflow is triggered and it copies the item to another list and then deletes the item from the current list.

The list that the item is copied to is supposed to start a workflow on item creation that pauses until a determined date. However it seems that sometimes the workflow starts and sometimes it does not. If it starts it works fine, but if it doesn't start there's no error message or anything, it just doesn't start. I can start it manually and everything works ok but that's a horrible solution.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem too and I managed to make the workflow start automaticlly by creating the new item with a USER other than the SYSTEM ACCOUNT.

Try to create your new Item using an Account other than the SYSTEM ACCOUNT and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can allow the system account to run workflows...

stsadm.exe –o setproperty –propertyname declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled –propertyvalue yes

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem, and found somewhat of a solution.  When I had both "Manual Start" and "Start when item is created", it would never start.  However, once I removed the "Manual Start" checkbox, it seems to fire automatically at that point.